# Mongoose: return only values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose to query my User schema, which contains:

```
var usersSchema = new Schema( 
    {
        email : String,
        regId : { type : String , default : '' },
        lastName : { type : String , default : '' },
        ...
    });
```

I need to get `getId` property values for the array of emails i have. Currently i am trying to do:

```
db.model('users').find( { email : { $in : arrUsers } }, { regId : true, _id : false }, function (err, res) { ... }
```

I receive this array: `[{ regId : "..." }, { regId : "..." }]` .

What i want to receive: `{ "...", "..." }` .

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks a lot !!!

EDIT: I am interested in doing the for loop on the database side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use additional [underscores](http://underscorejs.org/) map function:

```
var regIds = _.map(res, function (element) {
  return element.regId;
});

//regIds = ['..', '..'] as you've expected
```

Comment: Or just use the built-in array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function which is available in node.js.

Comment: @Anton Savchenko, Is there a way to do this at database side?

Comment: Probably you can use native mongo map function (from native driver) like so [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map) or deal with aggregation also from the native driver. I'm a bit unsure about such functionality in Mongoose, cause each object in collection is representation of the search result, and then you should deal with it like with collection, not like with the simple array.